# Im trying to add items to a text field in Java using NetBeans 6.9.1

Tags: java, desktop-application, jtextarea

My code in the action for a button press is:

```
@Action
public void add() {
    int miles=Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
    double km=miles/.621;
    jTextArea1.add
}
```

As you can see, I didn't finish the jTextArea1 code.  I just want to add a new line every button press that is something like "1 mile(s) = XX km" (with XX being the km variable)

I'm not clear on how to add text to the jTextArea1 though, as this is only my second day using the DesktopApplications, previously I only did console apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call:

```
jTextArea1.append("Text goes here\n");
```

Also, start reading [Oracles Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/) instead posting new question every 5 minutes.

Regards.

Comment: i used 
jTextArea1.setText(jTextArea1.getText()+"\n"+miles+" miles = "+two.format(km)+" kilometers");

Comment: Although i guess your way is probably more efficient, thanks for the answer! ill accept it as soon as i can